# How do I silence or muffle creaky floorboards?

Tags: hardwood-floor

My house was built in 1920 and we live in Western NY. The floorboards on the stairs and the whole second story of the house creak very loudly with every step we take. It's not only annoying, but it's waking our 8mo daughter at night and during her naps. We can't afford to carpet the floors, nor can we afford to replace the floorboards completely. This might be a total lost cause until we move to a new house, but I want to know if anyone has ANY suggestions for helping quiet my noisy house. Please and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of products marketed for this purpose which basically drive headless screws through the floor to fix the boards in place so they can't move. Haven't tried them, but reportedly they work.

The other solution is to learn to ignore the creak. It's amazing what sounds we can learn to filter out once we accept that they're just part of the environment -- traffic noise in the city, screaming hordes of crickets in the country, my grandfather clock, ...

Comment: When it was just the two of us, we learned to live with it. My husband even said it is kind of an unadvertised security feature because no one can get up the stairs without waking us up! But the problem is it is waking out daughter.

Do you know the name/brand of these headless screws and where I can find them?

Comment: Similar products are sold under multiple names, but one example is http://www.homedepot.com/p/Squeeeeek-No-More-Stops-Floor-Squeaks-From-Above-the-Floor-3233/100662995 -- endorsement not implied. However, I'd also point out that my niece has grown up in a room without a door (it was supposed to be the library; she was a surprise) and without the adults in the household trying to be especially quiet, and as a result has learned to sleep through most normal noises up to and including doors and conversation. Kids adapt, if we don't overprotect them.

Comment: @thesmallestone, the Japanese made floors for their palaces that were intentionally designed to squeak loudly. They were called  Nightingale or Uguisubari floors. They were intended to act as an alarm system so the inhabitants could here the approach of...ninjas.. I guess. Not helpful but an interesting footnote.

Comment: @paperstreet, the "rules" say to avoid this type of discussion, but your comment made me laugh! Thanks for that piece of silly trivia  :)

Comment: @keshlam, I more than understand what you're saying about getting my baby used to sleeping through noise. She sleeps well with a white noise machine in her room and normal background noise in our house (tv/radio, me cleaning or shuffling around the house [downstairs where the the floors don't creak], our cats running/playing, traffic, birds, other noise outside her window). However, sudden, loud noises such as the sharp noise of the floorboards wakes her. My question was how to avoid the noise, not how to acclimate my daughter to sleep through it. I do still appreciate your other suggestions.

Comment: @TheSmallestOne I made a list of name/brand products at http://guides.obviously.com/Fixing-Squeaky-Hardwood-Floors/1277

Answer (score 1):

Talcum powder (and some other materials) can be dusted into the cracks for a temporary (months not decades) kind of fix.